# redirecting request via .htaccess in yii

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii, server

I'm working on a yii 1 project and I have written a .htaccess file, that for every request checks to see :
if the request wants a file then it must receive it directly , otherwise the request must get to index.php and starts a yii application instance to handle it. 
here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css
```

and this is my file structure:
[image]

but with every request, I get an **Internal Server Error**. how should I edit my .htaccess?

Comment: Syntax seems ok. Did you have mod_rewrite enabled? What does your apache error log say?

Comment: this is what it says: this is what is it says:<br>Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log". What does the apache server error log say?